# Beginner's Question about Plotting in R

Tags: r

Alright, so I'm new to R, and I imagine what I'm trying to do should be very simple. I want to use plot(x,y), but then add the curve lm(y~x^2) over the plot. I'm sure I could add more detail this, but I am not sure what is needed, so I'll be vigilant to answer any questions you all may have. I appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is entirely about the use of R. It is not appropriate for SO either, because "please give me the code" questions are not welcome there. Please read the help about software-related questions.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the suggestion. Didn't mean to disturb.

Comment: use of `lines()` on the result of `fitted()` (if you have lots of nicely placed x's) or `predict()` (if you need to give x's to get a nice curve) would do it. Alternatively, using `curve` with `add=TRUE` where you make a function from the fitted coefficients could work

Answer (score 3):

```
x <- 1:10
set.seed(42)
y <- x^2+3 + rnorm(10)
plot(x,y)

#I assume you actually want this, i.e., fit a quadratic function:
fit <- lm(y~I(x^2))
pred.fit <- function(xnew) predict(fit, newdata=list(x=xnew))

#add curve
curve(pred.fit, from=min(x), to=max(x), n=1e3, add=TRUE)
```

[image]